# Library for creating MySQL queries from Java Script (other than Sequelize)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

Is there any good tool (library) to create MySQL queries from JS objects? I'm mainly interested in a low level tool, without instantialization and instance methods. Pure SQL output, but built dynamically from variables input, so you don't have to create the SQL script from strings.

I have tried Sequelize, but at some point it just starts to cause more problems than it solves. I can consider Sequelize alternative if such exists and is better.